# Maven, can't see my h2 class

Tags: maven, h2

I have some problem with my university project

I'm trying to connect to my h2 database but i'm failing on it.
I'm include it Maven dependencies but it still doesn't work.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.186</version>
    </dependency>
```

I get only classnotfoundexception

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] a)
{
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test");
         Statement stat = conn.createStatement()) {
        stat.execute("create table test(id int primary key, name varchar(255))");
        stat.execute("insert into test values(1, 'Hello')");
        try (ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from test")) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because the h2 db driver classes are not in the classpath at runtime. You should bundle them with your app's `jar` file, if they are not somehow made the part of the app's classpath.

Use [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html), or maven-jar-plugin to *bundle* the dependencies with your app's jar (in this case it is called the Uber jar) so as to make it single independent *runnable* jar.

Comment: Actually, it was already in classpath. After i add `public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception` this problem is gone. It seems weird to me. Anyway, thank you

Comment: Already in the classpath, how? Are you running your app as `java -cp <h2-driver.jar>:your-jar.jar YourMainClass`?